# plotting a 3D plot in MATLAB from struct

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to construct a 3D plot from some data that I have collected. The data is in a multi-struct.

For example, `a.b.c.d` (where `a` is a struct, and `b`(also a struct) is in `a`, and `c`(also a struct) is in `b`; and `d`(which is in c) is the field). The data is stored as this:

```
[ -7.87950284920632 -14.0701803040634
 -10.4668280400161   -5.84992824233833
  22.7819823970414   21.2561603536408]
```

I have ~180 rows of this data and I'd like to load it and construct a 3D plot. I've tried a bunch of plots from MathWorks website (`scatter3`, `plot`, `mesh`, `surf`) however I am unsure on how to load the data in.

Or is there a way to plot them 1 by 1 and do an overlay of all the plots?
image of data:

[image]

Comment: Do the data represent `X Y Z` values, as in, are the dimensions always 3×N? In what fields do the data reside, only in the `d` leaf in all subfields, or...how is it structured?

Comment: yes, they are X Y Z values. I've attached an image in my original post. The dimensions are in the form of 3x2 matrix.

edit: I do not have enough reputation so I had to link it instead of embedding it. The data is in the "pos" field of the struct. So for example, if my struct is A and it has a struct in it B, and that has a struct C in it; there is a field with the data in it (D).

A.B.C.D <- if I type this in the command window, I can see the data.

Answer (score 0):

(after the discussion below, it turns out the OP's struct is a 1×182 multidimensional `struct`, for which the subfield `pos` contains data of size 3×`N`, where 0 ≤ `N` ≤ 6).

Then something like this should do:

```
figure
clf, hold on

% Replace with actual names
if isfield(A, 'B') && ...
        isfield(A.B, 'C') && ...
        isfield(A.B.C, 'pos')

    % Concatenate all the "pos" data into a single 3×N array
    pos = [A.B.C.pos];

    % And draw the XYZ data into a scatterplot
    plot3(pos(1,:), pos(2,:), pos(3,:), ...
          'r.',...
          'Markersize', 10);
end
```

Comment: @prim3 that probably means it didn't reach the `plot3` command. If you put a `disp('HERE')` right in front of the `plot3` command, does that print anything on the MATLAB command window? Because if not, that means you've typed something in the names incorrectly...

Comment: It does. it prints "HERE". also pos in this line: `pos = A.B.C.pos;` is showing an empty matrix of 3-by-0.

Comment: @prim3 and you are sure that all the elements in `pos` are not `NaN` or `inf`? Perhaps also try `axis tight` after the `plot3` command

Comment: the very last value is 0. and the first 2 are [ ] only. maybe thats causing it? can we exclude that somehow?

Comment: @prim3 no, 0 should be plotted just fine. Not sure, set a breakpoint prior to the plot command and explore why it's not plotting; this code works over here

Comment: sorry I haven't used axis/breakpoints. could you show me if you have time? I tried: `axis(a.b.c.d, 'tight')` but I get an error

Comment: @prim3 `axis tight` or `axis('tight')` is the command to use. You can set breakpoints (in functions, not in scripts) by clicking on the thin bar next to line number in the MATLAB editor. Then, when a red dot appears, just run the script/function and MATLAB will stop there right in the middle of the execution, allowing you to inspect what exactly is in memory prior to the call to `plot3`. If you're using a script rather than a function, well, then just select the code you want to run and press F9, which will allow you to do the same.

Comment: thanks I added the axis tight and just ran the debugger. it seems like the figure window opens at `if isfield(A, 'B') && ...`

Nothing else changes except the addition of pos to the workspace which is an empty matrix (3-by-0).

Comment: @prim3 aha, now I understand -- there is no data to plot! Apparently, the `pos` field contains no data (if any dimension of an array is 0, that means the array is empty).

Comment: that doesn't make sense though? In the image above, we can clearly see data in the 'pos' field. what could be the problem?

Comment: @prim3 ...is there more than 1 `pos` field?

Comment: Rody--there is only 1. I think the problem is that its reading only the first CELL of that column. The data is as follows (from the top):

`[]`
`[]`
`[-10.9748415759465;-8.15837813989951;22.0190713764145]`
`[-10.9748415759465;-8.15837813989951;22.0190713764145]`
`[-10.9748415759465;-8.15837813989951;22.0190713764145]`

So you can see that the first 2 cells of the `pos` column are [] and [] which may be causing this? Is there any way we can choose which column to start with?

Comment: hi Rody, I get this error:
`Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but` `there were 182 results.`

`Error in phantom (line 91)`
   `pos = [ds1.res4.senres.pos{:}];`

Comment: @prim3 it seems you have a multi-dimensional structure...Is that so? Do the dimensions carry any meaning?

Comment: well, its a nested structure if thats what you mean? here is the data: http://pastebin.com/kyQpD8tt

You can see that it starts at 1 and ends at 182. My interest is only from 32-181. also I get an error when I run the code:

`Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.`

`Error in phantom>@(x)[x{:}]`

`Error in phantom (line 91)`
 `pos = cellfun(@(x)[x{:}], {ds1.res4.senres.pos}, 'UniformOutput', false);`

Comment: Hmm the pastebin is gone...can you send me a MAT file on (my last name) (at) (a well known email service from google) (dot com)

Comment: @prim3 are you still having this problem? Please send me the data via wetransfer or dropbox or pastebin or email (see my other comment)

Comment: i've sent it rody!

Comment: @prim3 I've received it; check the latest update to my answer